# CORS block only localhost request

Tags: express, nginx, cors, passport.js

I have a problem with my server developed in EXPRESS and hosted on NGINX.

I use passport.js for user authentication, even if I don't think this is the problem, and when I try to login from localhost I get an error while if I run it by uploading it to my domain I don't get it wrong and it works correctly, so I think it's a CORS problem blocking localhost requests.

**NGINX default**

```
server {

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name api.mysite.com www.api.mysite.com;

location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3007; #whatever port your app runs on
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        if ($http_origin ~* (^https?://([^/]+\.)*(mysite)\.com$)) {
                set $cors "true";
        }

        if ($http_origin ~* (^http?://([^/]+\.)*(localhost:3006))) {
                set $cors "true";
        }

        if ($http_origin ~* (^https?://([^/]+\.)*(192.168.1.21:3006))) {
                set $cors "true";
        }

        # Nginx doesn't support nested If statements. This is where things get slightly nasty.
        # Determine the HTTP request method used
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                set $cors "${cors}options";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                set $cors "${cors}get";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                set $cors "${cors}post";
        }

        if ($cors = "true") {
                # Catch all incase there's a request method we're not dealing with properly
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        }

        if ($cors = "trueget") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }

        if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";

                #
                # Om nom nom cookies
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
        }

        if ($cors = "truepost") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
        }

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**serverDev.js**

```
const sessionParser = session({
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
    cookie: {expires: 43200000,  secure: false }
})

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('ssl-cert/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('ssl-cert/fullchain.pem', 'utf8');

var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials,app);
```

**routes.js**

```
app.post('/Login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/Profile',
        failureRedirect : '/Login',
        failureFlash : false
    }),
    function(req, res) {
        if (req.body.remember) {
          req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
        } else {
          req.session.cookie.expires = false;
        }
    res.redirect('/Login');
});

app.get('/Profile', isLoggedIn, todoList.profile);

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

  console.log("isLoggedIn",req.isAuthenticated()) <--- THIS IS THE PROBLEM IN LOCALHOST RETURN ALWAYS FALSE 

    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/Login');
}
```

**passport.js**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query("use `Users`");
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
      if (err){
         return done(err);
      }
      var user = rows[0];
      done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: did you use `https://localhost` ?

Comment: I guess you are using SSL for api domain, then you switched to use localhost with SSL, it got error

Comment: I tried both solutions but the problem remains

Comment: you should use `http://localhost`, and can you share nginx part which listen on port 80

Comment: I am developing in React JS i cannot use http://localhost without ports, the only thing i can do is use port 80 like this:
"start": "PORT=80 HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=./.cert/cert.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=./.cert/key.pem react-scripts start"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else had this problem I solved it by configuring the `'express-session'` in this way

```
var session  = require('express-session');

const sessionParser = session({
  secret: 'your-secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12 // milliseconds * seconds * minutes * hours
        }
})
```